# SonarQube 7.1 upgrade bug LDAP

Tags: sonarqube7

I have updated the sonar: 6.7.1 -> 6.7.3 -> 7.0 -> 7.1. LDAP authorization (Authentication failed)/this a bug has ceased to work at version 7.1? to v7.0 LDAP works perfectly.

```
2018.05.18 11:06:14 ERROR web[AWNyQgM7ZS13jiunAAAQ][o.s.s.a.RealmAuthenticator] Error during authentication
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:81)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:83)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:59)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.selectByEmail(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonar.db.user.UserDao.selectByEmail(UserDao.java:165)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.UserIdentityAuthenticator.validateEmail(UserIdentityAuthenticator.java:140)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.UserIdentityAuthenticator.registerExistingUser(UserIdentityAuthenticator.java:109)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.UserIdentityAuthenticator.authenticate(UserIdentityAuthenticator.java:96)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.RealmAuthenticator.synchronize(RealmAuthenticator.java:142)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.RealmAuthenticator.doAuthenticate(RealmAuthenticator.java:110)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.RealmAuthenticator.authenticate(RealmAuthenticator.java:87)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.CredentialsAuthenticator.authenticate(CredentialsAuthenticator.java:61)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.CredentialsAuthenticator.authenticate(CredentialsAuthenticator.java:50)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction.authenticate(LoginAction.java:121)
        at org.sonar.server.authentication.ws.LoginAction.doFilter(LoginAction.java:102)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:87)
        at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:76)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?